# mysql find best matching word in one row

Tags: php, mysql, match, boolean-search

i have following table:

```
------------------------
| uid |  attrvalue     |
------------------------
| 1   |  Spray         |
| 2   |  strong        |
| 3   |  very strong   |
| 999 |  Creme         |
------------------------
```

now i have a query in php and like to find all rows where all queries are found.

```
SELECT * FROM attrtable WHERE MATCH (attrvalue) AGAINST ('Spray+very+strong' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I like that it only finds row 1 and 3. But the resultrows are 1, 2 and 3.

So its important that it founds all words or word combinations in the table rows. The query doesn't contain words or combined words which aren't in the table (I check this first).

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Please explain properly what you are asking

Comment: Thank you for comments. I like that it only finds row 1 and 3.

Comment: You need to define your rules, you say you want `Spray+very+strong` to match `Spray` but not `strong`, but both are in the query. Have a look at [stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `LIKE`, but the other way around to what your probably used to.

```
select query
from table1
where 'attrvalue' like concat(query,'%')
order by length(query) desc
limit 1
```